# Spark route resolution using queryMap

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

I am using Spark java for my API. I have the following urls

```
get("/template/:id") -> controller.getById(req, res).handle(req, res)
get("/template/:name") -> controller.getByName(req, res).handle(req, res)
```

Now my method getByName won't be call as the request will always map it to **:id** call. So is there a way I can handle this in spark-java. QueryMap might be useful I guess but I don't how to use it.

Comment: Could you give more context? Where are you using this code, and what's get() ?

Comment: get is http get request and I am using this in my SparkConfig class to map http requests to controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions you can use:

1. Create two different routes:

`get("/template/id/:id") -> controller.getById(req, res).handle(req, res);`
`get("/template/name/:name") -> controller.getByName(req, res).handle(req,res);`

2. Create only one route and use params:

`get("/template") -> controller.getByIdName(req, res).handle(req, res);`

And then call it with the params you want, for example:
`"/template?id=1234&name=Joe"` and parse the params inside `getByIdName` using `req.queryParams("id")` and `req.queryParams("name")`